# Is it possible to connect codebeamer with apache and access codebeamer through apache port?

Tags: linux, apache

I installed Codebeamer on Linux Ubuntu, connected MySQL, registered the service, and confirmed that it works when 'sudo service codebeamer start'.

I consulted the [official documentation](https://codebeamer.com/cb/wiki/93719#section-Ubuntu) but it didn't work.

Is it possible to connect codebeamer to apache?

Comment: This does not look like a programming related question (see [help/on-topic]), and on top, "it didn't work" is not a proper problem description (see [ask]), so that you have a chance to get an answer when you find the proper stackexchange site for this question. If you look at the articles linked above and the tag descriptions for the tags that you used ([tag:linux] and [tag:apache]), you'll find that this question is off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "connect codebeamer to apache"? If codebeamer can be used by http requests then sure, you can use an apache http server as a frontend server. Easiest would be to implement a simple reverse proxy in a vhost mapping the codebeam instance. But question is _why_ you would want to do that if that codebeamer application brings its own web server.